# Admob.java can't resolve ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am new to android studio and I am having a problem with admob.java it cant resolve ca-app-pub. and it says that the numbet of the ad unit is too long while it just a test adunit.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rMGb.jpg)

Comment: Firstly, don't post errors as images. SEcondly, it's a String meaning you need double quotes around it. I voted to close this as off-topic because of no code (applies when images are involved), though it should be closed as a simple typographical error

Comment: sorry about this! didn't mean to cause this trouble. I just needed help, and I am very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your id in `" "`

example

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("your admob id");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Grey Ish if answer helpful to you then you may check it as right answer and also may up it..!

Comment: Please I was banned from posting another question but I really need help. My interstitial ads show once every time the player looses or pass the level. i want it to show only after two levels and after 3 looses so that I can avoid bad user experience. If you could help me with I will be so thankful to you.